# Grid with columns inside button in code behind c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid

I'm trying to make a Grid (that contains a button and some labels) inside a button in code behind. I already did it with WPF and it works but when i try to convert it to code behind it ignores the columns.
I know that the declaration of the columns is correct because I tried it outside the button and the columns work perfectly. I don't know what to do anymore.

WPF code:

```
<Button HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Click="OuterClick">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Content="play" Grid.Column="0" Click="InnerClick"/>
        <Label Content="Con calma" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Label Content="Daddy Yankee" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Label Content="Album" Grid.Column="3"/>
        <Label Content="55" Grid.Column="4"/>
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

result WPF:
[image]

```
Grid waitingListItemPanel = new Grid() { HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch };
Button waitingListItemBar = new Button() { HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch, Content = waitingListItemPanel };
waitingListItemBar.Click += OuterClick;

Button playWaitingListItemButton = new Button() { Content = "Play" };
playWaitingListItemButton.Click += InnerClick;

waitingListItemPanel.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star) });
waitingListItemPanel.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star) });
waitingListItemPanel.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star) });
waitingListItemPanel.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star) });
waitingListItemPanel.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star) });
waitingListItemPanel.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(30) });

Label name = new Label() { Content = item.Name };
Label artist = new Label() { Content = item.Artist };
Label album = new Label() { Content = "Album" };
Label duration = new Label() { Content = item.Duration };

waitingListItemPanel.Children.Add(playWaitingListItemButton);
Grid.SetColumn(playWaitingListItemButton, 0);
waitingListItemPanel.Children.Add(name);
Grid.SetColumn(name, 1);
waitingListItemPanel.Children.Add(artist);
Grid.SetColumn(artist, 2);
waitingListItemPanel.Children.Add(album);
Grid.SetColumn(album, 3);
waitingListItemPanel.Children.Add(duration);
Grid.SetColumn(duration, 4);

NextUpStackPanel.Children.Add(waitingListItemBar);
```

result code behind:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what my error is. I am setting the `HorizontalAlignment = Stretch` for both the grid and the button while the button actually a `HorizontalContentAlignment=Stretch` need.